# Facebook Connect birthday perm

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I have a little problem with Facebook connect, about the birthday permission.

On the html body I have :

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="user_birthday, user_about_me" perms="email,user_birthday"> Login with Facebook </div>
```

On the header, for the jS, I have :

```
<script>
    // Additional JS functions here

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXX', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional init code here
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // connected
                FB.api('/me??accessToken='+response.authResponse.accessToken, function(user) {
                    var monthfb = user.birthday.substr(0,2);
                    var dayfb = user.birthday.substr(3,2);
                    var yearfb = user.birthday.substr(6,4);

                    $("input[id=year]").val(monthfb);
                    $("input[id=month]").val(dayfb);
                    $("input[id=day]").val(yearfb);

                    $("a.age_gate_submit").click();
                    alert('1');

                    console.log(user);
                    //$.cookie('age_gate', 'gohome',{ expires: 99 });
                    window.location = "home.html";
                });
            }
        });
    };

    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // connected
                FB.api('/me??accessToken='+response.authResponse.accessToken, function(user) {
                    var monthfb = user.birthday.substr(0,2);
                    var dayfb = user.birthday.substr(3,2);
                    var yearfb = user.birthday.substr(6,4);



                    $("a.age_gate_submit").click();
                    alert('2');

                    //console.log(response.birthday);
                    console.log(user);
                    //$.cookie('age_gate', 'gohome',{ expires: 99 });
                    window.location = "home.html";
                });
        }
        });
    }

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXX";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));


</script>
```

And when I click on my button, I have the good window, I accept the FB app, but no one of the functions jS is calling, so the window.locations isn't working. But whem I refresh it's ok I can take the birthday etc... So the problem is just on the moment I accept the app : how does the redirect please ???

Comment: Your problem isn't clear - what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your answer didn't help me.
But I found the solution :

I had to implement the FB.Event.subscribe(), this function works when a guy accept the log in.